# Google Sheets Pivot Table - Show dates in between

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with the cumultative number of shares for each stock and with different timestamps when a portfolio-change was made (invest or divest):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxdeBriRA9DgVclAWwfrz5ni1bZO94xwh0jFCghTLDg/edit?usp=sharing

Now I want to add the dates 'in between' (for every single weekday) the invest and the divest timestamps, where logically the cumultative numer of shares are more than zero.

**Example 'Apple':** I want the pivot table to show all the dates for every single weekday for Apple from 2013-05-08 to 2014-12-16 with the cumultative num of shares.

**Example 'AT&T':** Because there is no divest of AT&T Stocks, I want all the dates from 2020-04-06 to today.

I'd like to have this two examples with all the other stocks in one table to apply further functions. The purpose is to use the GOOGLEFINANCE function for the stock prices for each single day afterwards. But first, I need all the dates (where the number of shares is >0).

In the second sheet are the 'raw data'. I'm also fine if there is a better solution than using pivot table.

Thank you very much!
Greets Fabian

Comment: What do you mean by "all the dates"?  The Apple share price for every single weekday from 2013-05-08 to 2014-12-16?  Or at each month-end?  Or something else?

Comment: In the first step only the dates for every single weekday from 2013-05-08 to 2014-12-16. But also for AT&T an the other stocks, in one single table. Afterwards I can easily apply the GOOGLEFINANCE formula for the share price of each weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see [testFile](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12dyr8Fztl2fVnSABFVESYNEcSJYQB705ziW29aYoHSE/edit#gid=117884282).

Since your data contains large period of time, table with all dates included for all stocks would be really big and unusable so suggest to select one stock and create table for it.

Thus on testSheet in cell **B1** you select stock name you are interested in.
In cell **B2** select whether you want period for only historic data or up to date.

Following formula creates sequence of dates starting from first date for selected stock and up to date.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF($B$2="Today";
SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(FILTER('Stock Track Record'!A:A;'Stock Track Record'!F:F=$B$1))+1;1;
MIN(FILTER('Stock Track Record'!A:A;'Stock Track Record'!F:F=$B$1));1)))
```

Then next formula gets values from your initial data.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$5:$A;
QUERY({'Stock Track Record'!$A:$F};
"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
Where Col6 = '"&$B$1&"'";0);2;0);""))
```

And following calculates cumulative number of shares:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A5:A="";"";SUMIF(A5:A;"<="&A5:A;D5:D)))
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you very much for your solution. If your testFile would show all the stocks with their specific date-range, it would be exactly what I'm looking for.
I know this would be a lot of data... can you modify your solution to show all? I want to test the performance.

Comment: @incher91 added in testFile testSheet2. Problem is that with formulas it wont loop for each stock and generate dates for it, so it has to be large period from first date till today. There are 2752 dates times 28 stock items meaning 77056 rows in total really slowing down the file. In your case script may be more appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, you convinced me. I think script is the right way to go in this case. But your 2nd test file is also very nice!